# c# regex remove text between tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, html-parsing

I have text that contains many tags , for example:

```
<b class="bold"> some bold text </b> main text
<li>list text</li>
<script> script text </script>
```

and I need that all texts between tags and the tags will be deleted
in this example I should get "main text" because its the only text that has no tags.

I tried

```
   Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

but it will remove all the tags and not the text between them

I tried this

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"<(.+).*>.*<\/\1>");
var result = regEx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

with

```
<b class="bold"> bold </b>
main text
<ul>
<li> list </li>
<li> list2 <li>
</ul>
```

and i got

```
main text
<ul>


</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/

Comment: Add this info to question itself. Use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47718397/edit) link

Comment: Use an HTML Parser to parse HTML - [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this questions getting negged without comments, it's not very well written but it's clear what he wants to do.

Here you go:

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"<(.+).*>.*<\/\1>");
var result = regEx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Bear in mind that in a valid HTML document, all content is going to be contained within a tag of some sort so your result should always be nothing.

Caveat: this is by no means a comprehensive or complete solution, but it's a good base point to start from depending on what your real input data looks like.